# Conditional sum in excel for a GPA calculator?

Tags: excel, conditional-statements

I created a GPA spreadsheet in excel and have the basics working but I wanted to extend the functionality to exclude incomplete and pass/fail classes from the calculation. I've been trying to think how I could exclude any row that has a grade letter of I, P or F (fail as E is used for the normal grade letter F) but haven't found a solution yet. Is this possible with out creating a VBA script?

I have 5 columns one for the GPA and then Course/Credits/Grade/Points with each row having the information on one course. Points is credits * grade letter value (A = 4.0) this is to make sure the GPA is weighted correctly. GPA is currently just totalPoints/totalCredits =SUM($D2:$D10)/SUM($B2:$B10)

```
Course,Credits,Grade,Points,GPA
IT110,3,A,12,2.392307692
CS101,3,A-,11.1,
CALC1,4,C,8,
IT101,1,P,0,Don't include Pass/Fail courses
ENG101,2,I,0,Don't include incompletes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate an overall GPA (excel 2007 +)

```
=SUMIFS(D2:D10,C2:C10,"<>P",C2:C10,"<>I",C2:C10,"<>F") / SUMIFS(B2:B10,C2:C10,"<>P",C2:C10,"<>I",C2:C10,"<>F")
```

Some explanation of sumifs. ( http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumifs-function-HA010047504.aspx)

It takes several ranges. first, a "sum_range", then it takes pairs of arguments. a criteria range, then the criteria. as many pairs as you like. (here I did 3). It sums up in the sum range provided that each cell in range meets ALL criteria that you listed. (<> is Excels not equals operator)

Comment: Nice thank you for the explanation I was trying SUMIF for the first time today I didn't know the difference between SUMIF and SUMIFS.

Comment: No problem. The "IFS" functions have the multiple criteria. In the case of sumif, the argument order changes (see tool_tip in excel for exact order)

Comment: Yeah after your example I figured the IFS meant plural. :) This is really nice to know thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

example

```
 col a    col b   col  c   col d   col  f
```

row 1,,,,5,,,,,,,,6 ,,,,,,,1,,,,,,,2,,,,,,,,=7(result display in col f)

here input in all col any number but col f display addition only 2 and 1 (add every col 2 & 1)

others number not add

Answer (score 0):

I have only a vague idea what a GPA is but based on the data in your question:

```
=SUMIF(C:C,"<char(69)",D:D)/SUMIF(C:C,"<char(69)",B:B)
```

produces the same result as the accepted answer, is half its length uses a function that is more widely available.